# JQuery Dynamic tables

Tags: jquery, datatables, dynamic-tables

I've been trying to add dynamic tables to my registration page for a full day now and I am literally at the place where I started. I need to create a table where the user can edit, delete, and add new users. I've tried using datatables plugin and very few people have been able to help me out, and I've been reading all the examples on the website but they're tutorials are really pretty bad. I've been looking so many places and haven't got anywhere, can someone recommend a good way to add dynamic tables into your form or try answer my previous question about datatables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449907/jquery-datatables-add-row).

Comment: `dataTables` is a bit verbose, but I use it often and with no problems at all.

Comment: @moonwave99 that doesn't help me what so ever. But thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

It has a good inteface, it's free, very configurable and based on jQuery framework using jQuery UI look and styling.

For example see "Live Data Manipulation" -> "Add row" on [DEMO PAGE](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
Also have a big user base, so there is many howtos and other stuffs.

Only problem is that probably you must to learn many new things.
But worth it.